# Inconsistent behaviour between "Real User" and API

Tags: google-drive-api

1st of all, sorry for using that channel, but there's no other "open" communication channel for Drive SDK issues.

See, the thing is, if you try to access a Google Drive document that you do not have access to from your browser you get a nice warning that allows you to ask for access to the file (so, you get CONFIRMATION that the document exists, and that you DO NOT have access to it).

If you try to access a file you do not have access to from the API you get a 404, which does not confirm the document exists.

That is awfull, specially when working on your Google Apps domain, i.e: I may have access today to file X from user U and tomorrow user U looses access to this file (ie: change of ownership) from the API I will get a 404 with absolutely no pointer to where I should look for that file or if it even existss!!

From the browser you'd just "ask for access" and wait, but from the API you have two options: a) assume the file is gone or b) query for that file from EVERY user account you know about.

So, that goes to my suggestion/request:
Please do not respond to a 404 when there's a better code for that, a 403 would be nice..
Also, please, add a pointer about "where to go" on the response code.
You could also keep the 404 but adding the pointer of "a owner".

And, finally, find some way for service accounts to search **everything** inside a domain :)

thanks,
marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for raising this. There is a subtle difference here between the API and the user case: With the API it is much easier to send huge numbers of random IDs to find files. If we return 403 in those instances where files exist but have not been shared, this leaks some information to a script running this. If you don't have access to the file, you don't have the right to know if it exists or not.

In the user case, it is much more difficult to try many file IDs until you find one that you want. It simply takes too long in the browser, so this is a more acceptable risk. If you are clicking on a link, for example, you already know the file exists so no extra information has been leaked.

Service accounts searching for all files in a domain is an excellent feature request, thank-you. It's not available right now though, sorry.

Comment: Would it be possible to, when working inside a domain, when the API answers with a 404 give the pointer to the owning user? (As long as it is inside the same domain) at least for service accounts. Or make it a google apps option.
thanks ;)